# « Mutualiser leurs infrastructures » : usuel, savant, nuances ?

Tags: sens, usage, synonymes, commerce, connotation

On apprend que [mutuel](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/mutuel) est un dérivé savant du latin [*mutuus*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=mutuus), avec le sens de *réciproque entre deux ou plusieurs personnes*, attesté au 14e. Hormis l'adverbe et le substantif dérivé en moyen français, les autres dérivations, comme mutuellisme, mutualisme et leur appellatif, se produisent surtout au 19e. On ne parle pas du verbe, qu'on ne retrouve ni au DHLF ni au TLFi. Au Larousse, on a le verbe [*mutualiser*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mutualiser/53462?q=mutualiser#53111) qu'on définit comme « faire passer (un risque, une dépense) à la charge d'une mutualité, d'une collectivité. » Au GDT on parle des finalités du sens du verbe en disant qu'on mutualise « pour en optimiser l'aspect économique, l'accessibilité ou l'efficacité. » D'autre part on a [collectiviser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/collectiviser) pour, entre autres, *nationaliser*, souvent au profit de l'État dans ce sens. Il y a aussi un syntagme comme la *[mise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mise/2) en [commun](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commun)* dans le sens d'un changement des propriétés vers une mise en disposition pour le plus grand nombre, ensemble.

---

> Alexandre Taillefer a expliqué que les commerçants devaient se
>   regrouper et « mutualiser leurs infrastructures » et leur logistique
>   afin d'être aussi efficaces qu'Amazon [...] D'ailleurs, il dit
>   « croire de plus en plus qu'il faut réfléchir pour créer un Facebook
>   et un YouTube québécois ».
>
> [ [*Alexandre Taillefer veut créer un Amazon québécois*](http://affaires.lapresse.ca/economie/commerce-de-detail/201703/22/01-5081086-alexandre-taillefer-veut-creer-un-amazon-quebecois.php), dans *La
>   Presse* du 22 mars 2017, Marie-Eve Fournier ]

---

- L'emploi de *mutualiser* est-il courant aujourd'hui ; est-il usuel
  dans le monde des affaires ?
- On pourrait imaginer pourquoi on n'aurait pas voulu parler de
  *collectiviser* (mais on a parlé de barrages hydroélectriques dans l'article), mais y aurait-il une différence entre *mutualiser* et
  *mettre en commun* ? Le verbe mutualiser est-il senti comme un dérivé savant ? Quelle connotation aurait-il qui aurait pu motiver son
  emploi dans le propos rapporté de cet homme d'affaires ?
- A-t-on une idée de pourquoi la journaliste a décidé de mettre le
  verbe et son complément entre guillemets : est-ce pour rapporter fidèlement le propos ou pour signifier quelque chose à propos de l'expression ?

Comment: If I saw this use of “mutualize” in English, I’d see the quote marks as signaling an iffy use of the word, ‘cause I usually think of the mutualization of ONE company (going from being owned by stockholders to being owned primarily by employees/customers), & not of SEVERAL companies combining resources; but given the answers so far & the author’s style of putting lots of snippets in quotes, I doubt if this is the case here. Maybe Taillefer was using a word somewhere between “collectivize,” w/its “leftist” feel, & “amalgamate/conglomerate” which to me at least, have “capitalist pig” undertones.

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks! You could easily make a quick partial answer out of that insofar as the second point is concerned. There may be sth. cultural too which yields a different connotation; for instance my perception of _collectivize_ in Fr. is influenced by concepts such as universal medicare and such. But I believe what you describe has its equivalent nuances in Fr., which may or may not be exactly similar to those undertones you speak of, but close enough. Also, and this is the case with your comment as well as with the answers, the idea it's not _several_... but what about _mutual_ funds?

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que c'est assez courant, en tout cas pas surprenant du tout, et je l'ai déjà entendu en France avec ce sens-là. D'après [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutualiser&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutualiser%3B%2Cc0), l'utilisation du mot explose depuis 1990. *Mutualiser* n'est pas forcément savant, mais plutôt technique, donc plus précis que *mettre en commun*. Je ne connais pas les détails, mais on imagine que *mutualiser* évoque une structure économique bien définie. Je pense que les guillements ici serait plutôt pour rapporter les propos d'Alexandre Taillefer sans tels quels.

Answer (score 2):

> L'emploi de mutualiser est-il courant aujourd'hui ; est-il usuel dans
>   le monde des affaires ?

Je vais te répondre à partir de ma propre expérience : **oui**.

C'est sans doute le terme le plus utilisé dans ce contexte (ainsi que
dans le milieu des systèmes d'information).

> On pourrait imaginer pourquoi on n'aurait pas voulu parler de
>   collectiviser [...] y aurait-il une différence entre mutualiser et mettre
>   en commun ? Le verbe mutualiser est-il senti comme un dérivé savant ?
>   Quelle connotation aurait-il qui aurait pu motiver son emploi dans le
>   propos rapporté de cet homme d'affaires ?

*Collectiviser* me semble également correct, mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu. Je ne saurais dire pourquoi l'un est utilisé plus que l'autre, je pense que c'est avant une question de choix de jargon plutôt que de sens.
Je ne vois pas de différence avec *mettre en commun*. Ceci dit, je pense que *mutualiser* est un terme plus professionnel, plus technique, que *mettre en commun*.

Par ailleurs, il y a dans *mutualiser* une notion de fusion, qui va au-delà du simple partage et qui relève de la stratégie d'une entreprise.

> A-t-on une idée de pourquoi la journaliste a décidé de mettre le verbe
>   et son complément entre guillemets : est-ce pour rapporter fidèlement
>   le propos ou pour signifier quelque chose à propos de l'expression ?

Je pense que le journaliste a fait ça dans le but de surligner ce terme, de le mettre en avant par rapport au reste du texte, tout simplement.

Answer (score 1):

Mutualiser témoigne d'une volonté individuelle de partager quelque chose dont on a besoin,  d'existant ou à créer,  avec d'autres dans le même cas et ce dans le but d'optimiser ses propres coûts. C'est du libéralisme éclairé.
 Collectiviser  est plus global : on  met tout en commun, ce qui est à toi est à moi, ou plus exactement au groupe, que j'en ai besoin ou pas. C'est le communisme des débuts.
Les guillemets représentent probablement une citation mot pour mot.